# How to encode keywords for rotten tomatoes?

Tags: api, encoding, urlencode, url-encoding, rotten-tomatoes

I try to query movie called `Kokowääh` from rotten tomatoes API.

If I put it address bar in browser, I get back result: http://www.rottentomatoes.com/search/?search=Kokow%E4%E4h

But If I send via API, I get no result.

http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?apikey=MYKEY&q=Kokow%E4%E4h&page_limit=3

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

The Rotten Tomatoes API expects international characters in the query parameters to be encoded using UTF-8, and then percent-encoded.

If you look at their [I/O Docs](http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/io-docs) example page and ask it to generate an URL for the search "Kokowääh", you gen an URL like:

```
http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?q=Kokow%C3%A4%C3%A4h&page_limit=10&page=1&apikey=
```

Here you can see that there are two percent-encoded bytes per character, where each couple of bytes are the UTF-8 encoding of one character.